# group detection in large data sets python

Tags: python

I am a newbie in python and have been trying my hands on different problems which introduce me to different modules and functionalities (I find it as a good way of learning).

I have googled around a lot but haven't found anything close to a solution to the problem.

I have a large data set of facebook posts from various groups on facebooks that use it as a medium to mass send the knowledge.

I want to make groups out of these posts which are content-wise same.

For example, one of the posts is "xyz.com is selling free domains. Go register at xyz.com"
and another is "Everyone needs to register again at xyz.com. Due to server failure, all data has been lost."

These are similar as they both ask to go the group's website and register.

P.S: Just a clarification, if any one of the links would have been abc.com, they wouldn't have been similar.

Priority is to the source and then to the action (action being registering here).

Is there a simple way to do it in python? (a module maybe?)

I know it requires some sort of clustering algorithm ( correct me if I am wrong), my question is can python make this job easier for me somehow? some module or anything?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function called `geturls` that takes a string and returns a list of urls contained within, I would do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

groups = defaultdict(list):
for post in facebook_posts:
    for url in geturls(post):
        groups[url].append(post)
```

Comment: Yes, that's a workable solution. (Duly noted :) ) but the post may or may not have urls. That was just an example. 

They have a source name for sure- but not the url everytime. Can I do anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

That greatly depends on your definition of being "content-wise same". A straight forward approach is to use a so-called **Term Frequency - Inverse Document Frequency** ([TFIDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)) model.

Simply put, make a long list of all words in all your posts, filter out stop-words (articles, determiners etc.) and for each document (=post) count how often each term occurs, and multiplying that by the importance of the team (which is the inverse document frequency, calculated by the log of the ratio of documents in which this term occurs). This way, words which are very rare will be more important than common words.

You end up with a huge table in which every document (still, we're talking about group posts here) is represented by a (very sparse) vector of terms. Now you have a metric for comparing documents. As your documents are very short, only a few terms will be significantly high, so similar documents might be the ones where the same term achieved the highest score (ie. the highest component of the document vectors is the same), or maybe the euclidean distance between the three highest values is below some parameter. That sounds very complicated, but (of course) there's [a module for that](http://code.google.com/p/tfidf/).

Comment: PS. For even fancier stuff to do with, well, loads of words, check out the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/)!